Can I use href and rel attributes in img tag in HTML5?
In this article https://alistapart.com/article/introduction-to-rdfa/#section9 the author says that i can use the href and rel attributes directly inside img tag. I never knew we can do it in html5. But this article is also a bit old, written in 2009. So can someone confirm this, if we can do this or not..? Any reference to the specification is helpful
I tried looking at the w3c schools website, for img tag's attribute list, i couldn't find the href or rel attribute over there, i don't have enough knowledge to read the specification.

It's not w3c schools; it's W3Schools. Very important, as it has no support and is in no way connected to the standards body w3c. In fact, HTML is now governed by the WHATWG here. As you can see, the img element does not have href nor rel attributes and using them there would make the HTML invalid.

@HereticMonkey can we use this in context of html+rdfa ?  i think since the article i mentioned is about rdfa in html, hence this should only be posible in html+rdfa context and otherwise parsers would just ignore the attributes ...  do you think that's  the reason maybe... ?                                                                       and yes, its w3schools, it was a typo...  and html is a living language now...          and i didn't w3schools and w3c are unrelated, tbh....

ok, so i researched about it a lot on google, and the only logical reason i could found was that since html5 wasn't fully developed, and standardised until 2014, thus the article either is actually assuming that the use of href in img tag will surely be allowed in html5 or maybe during the time the article was written the plan actually was to allow such use but later it got changed to avoid confusion with html5 spec.....

RDFa is an HTML extension, which overrides normative content in the (X)HTML specifications. It’s specified by the W3C (not to be confused with W3Schools): HTML+RDFa 1.1 - Second Edition
Section 4 lists the changes to the HTML specification. The second bullet point answers your question:

[…] the following RDFa attributes are allowed on all elements in the HTML5 content model: […], @rel, […]. All other attributes that RDFa may process, such as @href […], are only allowed when consistent with the content model for that element, as defined in the HTML5 specification.

So in HTML+RDFa, an img element may have a rel attribute, but not an href attribute.

thanks for the link, much appreciated, but there's just one more important thing - you may check the author in the article I referenced in my question, he's "Mark Birbeck", now in any other case i wouldn't even had asked the question here, but he is a somebody in the context of semantic web and rdfa, you may really want to check his linkedin profile, seems to be one of the officials,   Why would a person with such background write something so ambiguous, or infact apparently plain wrong ?? This is reallly a dilemma for me... Why he wrote that we can use href in img tag ? Please reply

Mark birbeck's linkedin - https://www.linkedin.com/in/markbirbeck/?originalSubdomain=uk

look, infact mark birbeck was the one who proposed rdfa in w3c note forrm in 2004 in the first place - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDFa#History
